# Need help scraping Li class using Web scrapy

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

[Looking to use xpath to pull the vin but can't pull it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y8yg.png)

```
response.xpath(".//div[@class='vinDisplay']/text()").get()
```

Tried this but hasn't worked along with other variances.

Comment: Try `response.xpath(".//li[@class='vinDisplay']/text()")`.

Comment: what is the `.` for at the beginning of the xpath expression?  @zx485

Comment: can you please share URL as well?

Comment: need some more knowledge on question

Comment: The dot means: start evaluation from current node. If response starts at the document node, you can omit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
response.xpath("//li[@class='vinDisplay']/text()").get()
```